# Symfony 2: Install and enable the intl extension

Tags: php, windows, symfony, xampp

I'm using `XAMPP for Windows` and decided to try out `Symfony 2`.

As soon as I get to `Symfony Configuration` page it recommends me  to install and enable **intl**.

I tried reading `PEAR's` and `PECL's` guides, since I'm total **0** on this topic(started learning `PHP` recently), but nothing worked.

I found `php_intl.dll` inside my `C:\xamp\php\ext`. The `php.ini`'s `extension_dir=` is set to `"C:\xampp\php\ext"`. I was only missing the `extension=php_intl.dll` inside `php.ini`, so I added it.

Unfortunately it didn't work, and `Symfony` keeps asking me for **intl**.

Comment: tried ./ext for the extension dir? which php version is it?

Comment: Just did. It doesn't help. It tells me it can't load `php_bz2.dll` which is the first uncommented extension listed inside the php.ini

Comment: is it raw xamp or done some modifications on how php and apache are going to use each other?

Comment: I just ran `XAMPP`'s installation file, followed all instructions without modifying anything, and that was it.

Comment: php 5.4 comes with a builtin webserver, maybe it works that way. if that is no solution try to reinstall xamp or adjust its configs

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php

> This extension is bundled with PHP as of PHP version 5.3.0.
>   Alternatively, the PECL version of this extension may be used with all
>   PHP versions greater than 5.2.0 (5.2.4+ recommended).

also read my comment to your post above

Answer (score 11):

Whenever you make changes to `php.ini`, remember to restart `Apache`. Otherwise the changes won't take effect. You can do this in the `XAMPP Control Panel` by clicking the `stop/start` button in the `Apache` module row.

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps:

1. Copy all the file names starting with "**icu**" from *C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12* and paste to *C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin* (I am using WAMP. Figure it out yourself for XAMP.)

You can try. Nothing will harm. If you feel the things are not working, you can delete them. I am sure it will work for you 100%.

2. Uncomment the following line on C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini

   ```
   extension=php_intl.dll
   ```

It will work.

Comment: I did all these things but it is not working. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For Linux users:
Installing php5-intl made it work for me

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

found here: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php

Comment: This answer is not for Windows, but for linux. Please edit you answer to state that this is for linux only.

Answer (score 1):

## For OS X users:

1.Normally, the PHP is automatically installed on OSX. So, if you would like to use the XAMPP, or whatever apache server, you must change the path point to XAMPP. You can check the path by using:

```
$ which php
```

*(do not copy $ sign, it means than you should type this in Terminal, not php)*

You should get: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php` ,

if not, you will get `/usr/bin/php`.

This is OSX' php. So, you have to change it to XAMPP' php by using:

```
$ PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:${PATH}"
```

2.Run this command to download, unpack, compile and install ICU (you can choose different version is your Symfony required):

```
$ curl -sS -o /tmp/icu.tar.gz -L http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/57.1/icu4c-57_1-src.tgz && tar -zxf /tmp/icu.tar.gz -C /tmp && cd /tmp/icu/source && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && sudo make install
```

than run:

```
$ sudo pecl install intl
```

and specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found [DEFAULT] :

```
/usr/local
```

Pay attention to information in install report:

```
You should add "extension=intl.so" to php.ini
```

Don't forget to reboot Apache and check version:

```
<?php
if (extension_loaded('intl')) {
    echo "PHP: " . PHP_VERSION . "<br>\n";
    echo "ICU: " . INTL_ICU_VERSION . "<br>\n";
} else {
    die('OOPS! The intl extension is not enabled!');
}
```

Partially taken from here but modified to get success [Install PHP Internationalization extension (Intl) on XAMPP on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597100/install-php-internationalization-extension-intl-on-xampp-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

To activate this extension in Xampp, just edit your php.ini (i.e. in C:\xampp\php directory) and remove the semicolon to uncomment this line :

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

Eventually don’t forget to restart Apache !

Answer (score 0):

To solve this go to "c:\xampp\php\php.ini" open it in your editor and search for Dynamic Extensions then go down search for ;extension=php_intl.dll and enable it(remove ; to became like ) extension=php_intl.dll after that save your file  php.ini and restart your localhost