# Symfony config.php keeps asking for enabling intl extension, though it is enabled?

Tags: php, symfony, intl

I have come across this question which states exactly my problem, except that I'm using Wamp, not Xampp.

[`Symfony 2: Install and enable the intl extension`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218137/symfony-2-install-and-enable-the-intl-extension)

Though I enabled php_intl extension through the Wamp drop down menu, and making sure that the extension was not commented out in my `php.ini` configuration file, Symfony just keeps recommending me to enable `intl` extension.

I have visited the link in the accepted question:

[`http://php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php`](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php)

Still no luck. I have visited the [`ICU Homepage`](http://site.icu-project.org/) and even attempted to [`download it`](http://site.icu-project.org/download), and then I just don't know what file to download or what link to follow.

I'd like someone who can point me to the right direction. I'm quite new to PHP (only two sites developed with it), and am a total beginner with Symfony. And I also can't understand all those tricks with Pearl, PECL, Composer, etc. I feel completely lost.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Create a file `<?php phpinfo();` and check if it's there

Comment: I went to my Wamp's localhost address and clicked phpinfo(), and then I searched for `intl`. The search didn't find anything related to intl. =( Yet, I can locate the proper DLL in the `ext` subfolder of my PHP Wamp server, and I can see it ticked in the Wamp drop down menu.

Comment: Did you restart apache after you enabled it in `php.ini`?

Comment: I did click `Restart all services` from the Wamp drop down menu.

Comment: so now the question is only about WAMP. May be worth googling on how to enable `intl` in it properly then?

Comment: I have performed a search even before asking my question. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. =) The only thing I can find is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372888/intl-extension-php-intl-dll-with-wamp. And I find only the `icu*46.dll` files in folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having searched and searched again and again, I have found that the history information of my browser fooled me.

First, I have copied the `icu*.dll` files from my `%WAMP_INSTALL_DIR%\bin\php\php5.4.12` to my `%WAMP_INSTALL_DIR%\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin` as mentioned here: [`intl extension php_intl.dll with wamp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372888/intl-extension-php-intl-dll-with-wamp), and restarted all of my services.

Then, I had the idea of clearing my history, after having copied the files as above-mentioned, and it worked!

I do hope this will help others.

Answer (score 3):

Check the comments when you are using the app/check.php script:

```
* Configuration file used by PHP: /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

** ATTENTION **
*  The PHP CLI can use a different php.ini file
*  than the one used with your web server.
*  To be on the safe side, please also launch the requirements check
*  from your web server using the web/config.php script.
```

Make sure intl is enabled in the right php.ini file.

For getting started with Symfony I strongly recommend the video's from KNP University (knpuniversity.com). I thought they were excellent to get me started with Symfony. For composer enter $ php composer.phar list in the terminal to view all the options that come with composer.

Comment: I made sure to change the right `php.ini` file. Thanks for your contribution.