# No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/intl"

Tags: php, pear, pecl, intl

I'm trying to install intl for php. When I'm running `sudo pecl install intl` it gives me an error `No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/intl"`. I have tried to clear cache and also I tried to upgrade `pear` and `pecl`. Nothing. Here my pear and php versions:

`PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.6.3
Zend Engine Version: 2.6.0
Running on: Darwin iMac-bvc.local 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Tue Sep  1 21:23:09 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.50.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, problem solved! If you can't install **intl** by **pecl** you can just download from `[pecl.php.net]` the package which you need **(in my case it was `intl-3.0.0.tgz`)** and then install it by **pear** like that:  
`sudo pear install intl-3.0.0.tgz`  
After you have to add `extension="intl.so"` inside `php.ini` and then restart **apache**. If you want to check whether `intl` has installed or not you can use this command:  
`php -m | grep intl`  
If result is `intl` then you did it! =)

Comment: make that a real answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get it off the unanswered list:

---

Well, problem solved!

If you can't install intl by pecl you can just download from pecl.php.net the package which you need (in my case it was `intl-3.0.0.tgz`).

Then install it by pear like that:

```
$ sudo pear install intl-3.0.0.tgz
```

After you have to add `extension="intl.so"` inside `php.ini` and then restart apache.

If you want to check whether intl has installed or not you can use this command:

```
$ php -m | grep intl
```

If result is intl then you did it! =)

Comment: I get the following error while making: /private/var/folders/pear/intl/php_intl.h:33:10: fatal error: 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps:

1. Try this under mac `brew install homebrew/php/php70-intl`
2. Then open php.ini (you can use `which php` to help you).
3. Add, `extension = /usr/local/Cellar/php70-intl/7.0.25_20/intl.so`
4. And then use `php -m | grep intl`
5. If it works, the intl will be displayed.