# pecl can't find imagick package

Tags: php, imagick, pecl

I am attempting to install imagick on my mac. I have searched and read a lot...including this [excellent write up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060021/homebrew-install-new-formula-php72-imagick?noredirect=1&lq=1).

However, I am running into an issue with the final step and that is the actual install of the imagick package via pecl. I am receiving this error:

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/imagick"
install failed
```

I have gone to the pecl site and of course I see a host of released imagick packages, so I am unclear as to why this fails. Any ideas will be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953764/no-releases-available-for-package-pecl-php-net-intl

Comment: For some reasons, using "sudo" made it work for me. It was not found without "sudo" and found with it (using `sudo pecl install imagick`)

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, the error is because of expired/invalid CA certificates. You might want to update the certificate from pecl.php.net, or update the software, or try the following workarounds:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.7.0.tgz
pecl install --offline ./imagick-3.7.0.tgz
```

Or you can download the latest version here: https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick and run the 2nd command.