# No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/imagick"

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, pecl, php-8

First of all, I'm sorry if I'm posting a duplicated question. I know there are a few threads about installing imagick on an local machine. But I really can't find any way to fix my php installation.

I want to install the imagick extension for PHP 8.0 But when I try to install with the `pecl install imagick` command I get the following error:

```sh
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/imagick"
install failed
```

I am developing on a Macbook. Have a freshly installed [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/valet#introduction) installation. Installed my PHP 8.0 (with homebrew, via valet) and tried to execute `pecl install imagick`.

I have re-installed imagick & pkg-config with `brew reinstall imagick` & `brew reinstall pkg-config`. In that order. After that, I still get the same report.

I have ran `brew doctor` but don't think there is anything useful in there that could help me. Only some broken symlinks and Unbrewed header files. If you want I can upload the full output, but someone needs to help/tell me how to upload such a big snippet. Just putting it in this question without formatting seems like a bit too much.

---

**Possible duplicated that didn't help me so far:**

- [pecl can't find imagick package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002572/pecl-cant-find-imagick-package)

Comment: I would ensure that your install is updated with `pecl channel-update pecl.php.net` and then try again. You should consider if you really need to use this package or not; maintaining PECL packages can be a nightmare, especially when it's not supported by your package management system. Possibly worth noting that MacPorts does support this natively, so it would be as simple as `sudo port install php-imagick` on that system.

Comment: Also tried the channel-update command. Was already up to date. I've never had problems with pecl before, but I'll look into MacPorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it solved with `sudo pecl install imagick` but that might not be the preferred route.