# OSX Xampp Install PHP extension intl

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I found a lot of tutorials for installing intl extension but none of them is working for me. I get to install sudo pecl install intl but I get error:

pecl/intl is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.0.0
install failed

Can you someone help me how to install this extion on osx xampp?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: you could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597100/install-php-internationalization-extension-intl-on-xampp-on-mac