# Install PHP 7.0 Internationalization extension (Intl) on XAMPP on Mac

Tags: php, macos, php-extension, pecl, intl

I followed the instructions outlined here:

[Install PHP Internationalization extension (Intl) on XAMPP on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597100/install-php-internationalization-extension-intl-on-xampp-on-mac)

Ran sudo pecl install intl
selected the correct files from the Cellar

then this error happened:

> /private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/intl_error.h:24:10: fatal error:
>   'ext/standard/php_smart_str.h' file not found
>
> ## include
>
> ```
>      ^ 1 error generated. make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1 ERROR: `make' failed
> ```

No matter, did some research and found out that PHP 7.0.8 deprecated php.smart_str.h to php.smart_string.h

So given my scant knowledge of C++ I copied smart_string.h to smart_str.h and renamed all the headers from STRING to string.....

re-ran pecl -no luck....more errors......without knowing where the .c files are and remaking php (not really interested in going that far) since anyway I'm using XAMPP so that ended that option.

I have php 5.5 on my mac, deep in the usr/local/bin folder
so next step was to get pecl to use those files and generate an intl.so file....

Did that....I have the intl.so file so put it in the 'extensions' folder in XAMPP (for reference: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012)

Ran php and came up with this error:

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so'
>   - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so,
>   9): Symbol not found: _zval_used_for_init   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so
>   Expected in: flat namespace  in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so
>   in Unknown on line 0

I imagine it has to do with different versions?

In any case I can't get pecl to install intl without a make error in PHP 7.0.8 on XAMPP.  There is no documentation on this and you'd think that if you deprecate a header.h file you'd update all extensions?

Install intl.so in PHP 7 seems impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of research I was finally able to resolve this. [Detailed steps here](http://blog.dhawalmehta.com/2019/08/20/install-intl-php-extension-for-xampp-and-magento-for-macos-mojave/):

before you begin, check `which php` path is set. it should be `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php`. If not you can change it by `PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:${PATH}"`. [more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32404183/3672563)

Overall idea is to build the intl-extension from PHP source code on your own. Before you begin make sure you have installed Xcode. Also, install the latest version of autoconf. this might help:

```
brew install autoconf
```

Next download the version of PHP you use in XAMPP from php.net. I am using 7.1.18. This version worked for me: php-7.1.31, I’m guessing if you follow the steps it might work for 7.0 or 7.2 as well. Do let me know if it does or doesnt, I’ll update this post. Do not use PHP 7.3 for Magento 2.3.0, it is not supported.

Extract the tar.gz file using (I extracted it inside ~/Downloads/ folder )

```
tar -xzvf php-7.1.31.tar.gz
```

cd into the extracted folder

```
cd php-7.1.31
```

change to subfolder ext/intl

```
cd ext/intl/
```

Run these commands to build the extension

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/phpize
./configure --enable-intl --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php-config --with-icu-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/
make
sudo make install
```

you can now delete all files you downloaded and also the extracted folders.

Open /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini , and add `extension=intl.so`

Restart your Apache using XAMPP GUI and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, in 2022, this is the only work solution for MacOS 12.6.

Answer (score 1):

So far, it seems that extension intl.so for php is bundled with php
and should be compiled with php (intl --enabled).  XAMPP does not support this (as of Oct 2016), MAMP does.  I do not know about other distros.  However, if you're willing to recompile PHP 7, it's worth it just to do that and enable it during compiling.

So....I ran with MAMP.  Then I decided that I would simply install apache 2.4 and php 7 and Mysql without the stack and the junk that comes with MAMP or XAMPP and everything works like a charm... so if you need to use CakePHP or intl support etc... just drop XAMPP/MAMP and go with a standard install. I used homebrew (MacOS) and everything is working fine.

Update: As regards Windows, XAMPP does not default it, but you can add the module (dll) in php.ini and works like a charm

Answer (score -1):

The error means that XAMPP doesn't have PHP compiled with `intl`. You may try:

```
pecl install intl
```

but probably it won't work as well.

See: [PHP Bug #72879    Pecl install intl make error with PHP 7.0.8](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72879).

---

As for the workaround, try installing `memcached` extension instead of `memcache`, e.g.

```
pecl install memcached
```

Note: It also requires `libmemcached` package/library to be installed beforehand. For macOS, install via: `brew install libmemcached`.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanna try without homebrew, with native apache and php, look at my aswer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55131868/3692846