# Magento Xampp php.intl extension

Tags: php, magento, xampp

I'm trying to install **Magento 2.1** on my laptop using **XAMPP**.
The installation wizard gives me one error about the *PHP intl. extension*.

I found it in the *php.ini* file and i removed the semicolon before it.
With that thing i had been able to install it on my windows machine, but on mac it gives me always the missing extension check error.

Does anyone know how to fix that problem?

Comment: Well, maybe by installing that extension?

Comment: It is not installed by default on osx?

Comment: I cannot say, but you could simply check that.

Comment: have you restarted apache/fpm after you made change in config? use phpinfo to see which extensions you have loaded.

Comment: i followed the steps of that post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597100/install-php-internationalization-extension-intl-on-xampp-on-mac

and it goes, but when i put in the termina the command to install the php intl extension it prints me an error

1 error generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

Answer (score 0):

First of all stop the xampp/wamp and then kindly remove the starting semicolon ( ; ) from your xampp/php/php.ini the following code.

;extension=php_intl.dll
And then restart your xampp/wamp